# Хеш теги как в твитере

Tags: теги, хеширование

Здравствуйте уважаемые пользователи. 
 У меня к вам небольшая просьба:
Подскажите пожалуйста как мне сделать на своем сайте хеш теги как в твиттере или вк?

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема?

 1. придумай метку, например #
 2. пиши все в бд
 3. ищи, например like '#example'
 4. подсвечивай что то java scriptom на странице

Comment: `LIKE`? Для FTS? Зачем Вы это советуете?

Все нормальные люди строят индексы и получают свой поиск за `O(1)`.

Comment: @drdaemon, Что такое [FTS]( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTS) ?   
Full Text Search или File Transfer System ?  
Мне для самообразования.

Comment: причем тут file transfer system?)

Comment: @gorets ну остальные аббревиатуры с вики плохо подходят :) Эти две наиболее близкие тематике, просто если бы она значила первое, тогда было бы уместнее не «Для FTS?» а «Это же FTS!», поэтому усомнился в сокращении.

Comment: спасибо конечно, но мне бы сам код не помешал, я в кодинге не разбираюсь, я в основном в верстке, разумеется не бесплатно)

Comment: @mandrovich, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Answer (score 5):

Когда добавляется (или редактируется) публикация — ищите в ее тексте теги. Наиболее простой (но не всегда подходящий) инструмент — обычные регулярные выражения, поиск чего-то в духе `/#(\w+)/`.

Найдя теги записывайте идентификатор публикации, в которой они были найдены. В итоге, если представить в виде таблицы, у Вас получится что-то в духе:

```
+---------------+------------------------------------+
| Тег           |  ID публикаций                     |
+---------------+------------------------------------+
| теги          | 167956, 165489, 148204             |
| хэш           | 167956, 147666                     |
+---------------+------------------------------------+
```

(Для примера взяты два реальных тега и несколько записей с ними с ХэшКода).

В случае реляционных БД это может быть представлено, например, таблицей вида:

```
+---------------+-------------+
| tagname       | post_id     |
+---------------+-------------+
| теги          | 167956      |
| хэш           | 167956      |
| теги          | 165489      |
...............................
```

Когда нужно искать по тегу или их пересечению, достаточно простой работы со множествами. Выбираете множество идентификаторов всех записей, содержащих (или не содержащих) нужные теги, и выводите эти публикации.

Comment: в ответе не достаёт информации, как полученные теги преобразовывать в поисковые ссылки или что-то подобное в самой публикации

Answer (score 1):

Немного добавлю к ответу [[[[[[@drdaeman](/users/2694/drdaeman)](/users/2694/drdaeman)](/users/2694/drdaeman)](/users/2694/drdaeman)](/users/2694/drdaeman)](/users/2694/drdaeman).

Ну про преобразование то тут все же просто!

Если в тексте [[[[[[@drdaeman](/users/2694/drdaeman)](/users/2694/drdaeman)](/users/2694/drdaeman)](/users/2694/drdaeman)](/users/2694/drdaeman)](/users/2694/drdaeman) же написал

> Наиболее простой (но не всегда подходящий) инструмент — 
> обычные регулярные выражения, поиск чего-то в духе /#(\w+)/.

Ищите их в тексте и подсвечиваете.( как подсвечивать, да как угодно, как душа ляжет.)

Ну а поисковые ссылки обрабатываются так же как и обычные теги, но наверное просто по другому адресу.

Нашли мы хэштэг #лаборатория у него будет link примерно такого содержания

> <а href="/hashtag/#лаборатория">#лаборатория <\а>

Ну а по адресу /hashtag/ обрабатываем полученный хэштег.

ps

можно глянуть как сделано на ХЭШКОДЕ

```
<а rel="nofollow" href="/users/2694/drdaeman">@drdaeman<\a>
```